# Why my Firebase Cloud Firestore data document randomly showing?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Please check the image in the link, https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M9Wj.png
I type and created my documents starting from One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, and Seven like this but it showing randomly. and Also data is fetching in my app randomly. and wanted to fetch all those documents categorically. It should fetch documents like this in my app-
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
Seven

Comment: Those are the id's of your objects, they will be listed in alphabetical order on Firebase console. You can sort them differently using the filters. When in your app, you need to add sorting to your query, or sort them client side. If you need sequential fetching, you have to fetch them sequentially...

Comment: post your solution as an answer or  I can do it as [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki).so that other's could spot the workaround easier?

Comment: I have provided an answer below.please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the id's of your objects, they will be listed in alphabetical order on the Firebase console. You can sort them differently using the filters. When in your app, you need to add sorting to your query, or sort them client side. If you need sequential fetching, you have to fetch them sequentially.